# StumulSoft report don't load any data in first show

Tags: c#, winforms, report, localdb, stimulsoft

I have added a StiReport to my windows form application project. My report is connected to a view in visual studio local database.When I show report for first time it don't show any data. but when I close report viewer and execute the report again , It works normally and shows data. 
How can I fix this Issue ?

```
private void btnQtyChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StiVariable sv = new StiVariable("Vars", "IdSgn", typeof(int), grd.CurrentRow.Cells["IdSgn"].Value.ToString(), true);
    rep.Dictionary.Variables.Add(sv);
    rep.Compile();
    rep.Render();
    rep.Show();
}
```

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft assemblies do you use? Where do you create the rep instance and how do you load the report template?

Comment: I Use version 2015.2. I have created my report in my application by adding a stireport and I run it by above code

Comment: Try the latest build. Do you get the same result?